# How to set a threshold for LazyColumn/ViewPager before starting to scroll?

Tags: kotlin, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using the [experimental viewpager](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/) for Jetpack compose which is built upon `LazyColumn`/`Row`.

What I'm trying to do is to set some threshold of how much I need to move my finger before it starts to scroll to next page. The default behaviour is that as soon as I move my finger it starts to scroll, but I want to have a larger threshold of how much I need to move the finger before any visual scrolling occur.
I've looked at the `FlingBehaviour` parameter, but I don't see how to use that to accomplish what I want. (Or at least add some more "resistance" to flip between the pages, so it's not so sensitive)

Have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This threshold is controlled by the `flingBehavior` argument.

`PagerDefaults.flingBehavior(pagerState)` provides paging work, currently only animations are configurable, so you can't just provide your own instead behavior instead. But you can wrap it like this:

```
private class FlingBehaviourMultiplier(
    private val multiplier: Float,
    private val baseFlingBehavior: FlingBehavior
) : FlingBehavior {
    override suspend fun ScrollScope.performFling(initialVelocity: Float): Float {
        return with(baseFlingBehavior) {
            performFling(initialVelocity * multiplier)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun rememberFlingBehaviorMultiplier(
    multiplier: Float,
    baseFlingBehavior: FlingBehavior
): FlingBehavior = remember(multiplier, baseFlingBehavior) {
    FlingBehaviourMultiplier(multiplier, baseFlingBehavior)
}
```

Usage:

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
HorizontalPager(
    count = 10,
    state = pagerState,
    flingBehavior = rememberFlingBehaviorMultiplier(
        multiplier = 0.5f,
        baseFlingBehavior = PagerDefaults.flingBehavior(pagerState)
    ),
    modifier = Modifier
) { page ->
}
```

Comment: There is no PagerDefaults.flingBehavior() method anymore... This answer needs to be revisited. (Version 0.18.0)

Comment: @Ali_Waris It's still there, maybe you have an error because it's experimental? Also 0.18.0 is not the latest version, you can check it [here](https://github.com/google/accompanist/releases)

Comment: I know, 0.18.0 is not the latest, but due to some issues in the latest version, i cannot move to the versions 0.18.0+

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the amount of pixels (or % of screen) need to be scrolled before the next/prev page will be selected? Currently I need to scroll more than 50% of the page, so that the next/prev one is selected...I would like to only scroll 20% or so...50% on a landscape tablet is a verrrry long swipe....