# Swipe sensitivity for HorizontalPager in Compose

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I implemented a simple [HorizontalPager](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/#horizontalpager) which works mostly as expected. The app I develop is for one specific device, a 8" Tablet in landscape mode. At the moment it is required to swipe more than 50% of the screen-width to get to the next/prev page. This is a very long swipe and I would like to reduce that to make changing pages easier...

I played around with [fling behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69494226/how-to-set-a-threshold-for-lazycolumn-viewpager-before-starting-to-scroll) and tried to manually change pages when the [offset changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69494226/how-to-set-a-threshold-for-lazycolumn-viewpager-before-starting-to-scroll) or to intercept the touchevents...Nothing really lead to the desired behavior.

Since the "problem" seems so simple, I really hope that I have just overseen something. Do you have an idea what I could try?

Comment: how exactly have you tried? Something like `multiplier = 5f` with [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69495439/3585796) should definitely work

Comment: Alternatively you can copy `PagerDefaults.flingBehavior` source code and redefine it to your needs. There's no simple parameter like "screen scrolled percent", `flingBehavior` is the only option

Comment: I don't really think this is exactly what I expect. The fling is faster with the multipler = 5f, but what I want to change is, that the fling behavior is executed with less of a swipe. I think I don't want to change the fling behevior but the detection of a fling... If that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, it seems like in the current version of the snapper library (https://chrisbanes.github.io/snapper/) there is actually a way to achieve this by implementing the snapIndex (see https://github.com/chrisbanes/snapper/blob/main/lib/src/main/kotlin/dev/chrisbanes/snapper/SnapperFlingBehavior.kt ) parameter in rememberSnapperFlingBehavior(). Too bad this is  not yet supported in the HorizontalPager :/.

Comment: just copy `flingBehavior` [source code](https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/80fbb7d6711fdfb4135b175ea03be35550a92d12/pager/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/pager/Pager.kt#L117-L130) and provide different `snapIndex`

Comment: That was my plan, but lazyListState is internal and I don't see a way to build a flingBehavior with custom snapIndex, without the lazyListState... Or am I missing something? (https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/2248e5efc788f7dc0c0be26239d6020bc888f127/pager/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/pager/PagerState.kt#L77-L78 )

Comment: I don't see where you need `lazyListState`? for `flingBehavior` you only need `PagerState`, and for custom `snapIndex` it seems like you don't need anything at all - it's just a lambda

Comment: Ahh my bad! I had an older version where this method didn't exist and I was a little confused...Thank you! That looks like it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: `flingBehavior` internally does not implement the function that takes `snapIndex`. Even copying the implementation and adding `snapIndex` won't help as @jpm mentioned it needs a `lazyListState` so there is a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solved my problem, you can edit minFlingDistanceDp to change the sensitivity:

```
HorizontalPager(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            state = pagerState,
            count = noOfPages,
            flingBehavior = flingBehavior(pagerState = pagerState, noOfPages = noOfPages)
        ) { page ->
            //Content
        }


val minFlingDistanceDp = 150.dp

@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class, dev.chrisbanes.snapper.ExperimentalSnapperApi::class)
@Composable
fun flingBehavior(pagerState: PagerState, noOfPages: Int): FlingBehavior {
    var currentPageIndex = remember { pagerState.currentPage }
    return PagerDefaults.flingBehavior(
        state = pagerState,
        snapIndex = { layoutInfo, _, _ ->
            val distanceToStartSnap = layoutInfo.distanceToIndexSnap(currentPageIndex)
            currentPageIndex = when {
                distanceToStartSnap < -(minFlingDistanceDp.value) -> {
                    (currentPageIndex + 1).coerceAtMost(noOfPages - 1)
                }
                distanceToStartSnap > minFlingDistanceDp.value -> {
                    (currentPageIndex - 1).coerceAtLeast(0)
                }
                else -> {
                    currentPageIndex
                }
            }
            currentPageIndex
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I got webviews in my HorizontalPager. But it seems to be not working for me..

Comment: Please use `var currentPageIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(pagerState.currentPage) }` or there will be strange sliding rebound. Because the state cannot be retained.

Comment: For me the only way it works is putting the current page index like this:
val currentPageIndex = pagerState.currentPage

Comment: Note that this solution (like the question) is for the Accompanist Pager, which is now deprecated. Unfortunately the compose foundation PagerDefaults.flingBehavior does not provide a `snapIndex` parameter.

Comment: @NinovanHooff `rememberSnapperFlingBehavior()` has the `snapIndex` parameter. Maybe give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

`HorizontalPager` in foundation library version `1.5.1` now has a parameter in `flingBehavior` called `snapVelocityThreshold` to control the swipe velocity.

You can create your own flingBehavior with more sensitivity like this

```kotlin
val pagerState = androidx.compose.foundation.pager.rememberPagerState(
    initialPage = 0
) {
    imageList.size // A list of image urls to load in the carousel
}

androidx.compose.foundation.pager.HorizontalPager(
    state = pagerState,
    pageSpacing = itemSpacing,
    flingBehavior = PagerDefaults.flingBehavior(
        state = pagerState,
        snapVelocityThreshold = 5.dp
    ),
) { pageScope@ { page ->
    // Your pages go here
}
```