# In Jetpack Compose, Is there a way to make swipeable rows work better inside a scrollable LazyColumn?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I have `LazyColumn` that has `verticalScroll` modifier, and each child row also has a horizontal `swipeable` modifier. Everything actually works pretty well, but there is a bit of a problem when trying to scroll vertically -- if there's even a very slight horizontal movement, then the vertical scroll doesn't get triggered, and the horizontal swipe is triggered instead.

Is there any way to set a 'preference' for the vertical scroll, so that if there's any vertical movement, then the swipe shouldn't happen?

**Edit:**
I should clarify that I'm using the `swipeable` modifier on each row for swipe-to-dismiss functionality. It's got some custom functionality, which is why I'm not using the `SwipeToDismiss()` composable, but I did try running it using `SwipeToDismiss()`, and it has the same problem

Comment: Hi, it's been a while, but have you found a way to solve this ? I'm bumping in the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using HorizontalPager() inside your verticalScroll Column.

```
Column(
    Modifier
        .verticalScroll(scrollState)
) {
    HorizontalPager(/*...*/)
}
```

It is smooth by default but you can even modify the gesture of it by changing flingBehavour as described here:

[Swipe sensitivity for HorizontalPager in Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72444556/swipe-sensitivity-for-horizontalpager-in-compose)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How would a HorizontalPager fix the problem? as I said, I don't really have a problem with the swipeable modifier. Just a problem with the fact that it seems to be triggered with the slightest sideways movement when I'm trying to scroll up or down

Comment: By using HorizontalPager, you can edit minFlingDistanceDp to change the sensitivity.
but the initial sensitivity is ok too and HorizontalPager scrolls is not triggered with the slightest sideways movement.

Comment: But won't that prevent the vertical scroll from initialing? Regardless of whether or not the the sideways movement is triggered, it would be consumed by the HorizontalPager. And that means that the vertical drag would be consumed as well, unless I'm understanding it wrong.