# Change scroll distance before going to next page for HorizontalPager in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a HorizontalPager with a TabRow with two items. Currently you need to swipe almost the entire screen before it snaps to the next page. I'd like it to snap to the other page on a smaller scroll. This is my current code:

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    TabRow(
        selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage
    ) {
        Tab(
            selected = pagerState.currentPage == 0,
            onClick = { component.changeChild(0) },
            modifier = Modifier.height(53.dp)
        ) {
            Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                Text(
                    text = "First page"
                )
            }
        }

        Tab(
            selected = pagerState.currentPage == 1,
            onClick = { component.changeChild(1) },
            modifier = Modifier.height(53.dp)
        ) {
            Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                Text(
                    text = "Second page"
                )
            }
        }
    }


    HorizontalPager(
        pageCount = 2,
        state = pagerState,
        beyondBoundsPageCount = 1,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) { page ->
        when (page) {
            0 -> FirstPage()
            1 -> SecondPage()
        }
    }
```

I've tried to modify the `flingBehavior` in HorizontalPager, but nothing I've tried actually modifies the distance needed to swipe. I've also looked online, but all the questions are either for the old HorizontalPager from the Accompanist library, or the [Snapper](https://chrisbanes.github.io/snapper/) library.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72444556/swipe-sensitivity-for-horizontalpager-in-compose help?

Comment: @Raghunandan that question is for the Accompanist/Snapper library, and sadly doesn't apply to the Jetpack Compose implementation.

Comment: there is no direct way to do this i guess. you need to copy the pager source the state and modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is something called `positionThresholdFraction` in the `PagerState` class file, but unfortunately it's not changeable for now.
I have created an issue, you can find it [right here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/289153001). Feel free to click +1 right under the link so google will react faster.